# Invalid character warning in MVC razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to achieve the following output in javascript:

```
if (someCallback) someCallback();
```

Where "someCallback" is the value of a string from my viewmodel.

What I tried in my view was:

```
$("#btnOK").click(function() {
        @{
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.JavascriptCallback))
            {
                <text>
                    if (@(Model.JavascriptCallback)) @(Model.JavascriptCallback)();
                </text>
            }
        }
    });
```

This outputs what I want, but I get a warning on the curly bracket in "@{" stating "Invalid character."

Using @if also works but with even more warnings:

```
$("#btnOK").click(function() {
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.JavascriptCallback))
            {
                <text>
                    if (@(Model.JavascriptCallback)) @(Model.JavascriptCallback)();
                </text>
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to achieve this without getting a warning?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable warnings in a Razor page by putting the following in the view:

```
@{ #pragma warning disable }
```

Comment: It appears this may need a warning code number, but I can't find it for this warning. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(v=vs.80).aspx